# Copying the previous column value in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to copy the value from the previous column to the present column if there is a missing value, but there is something wrong in the code I wrote.

```
data X; 
input A B C D E; 
cards;
1 . . . 2
2 2 3 . .
3 3 4 5 6 
4 4 4 2 .
. . 6 . .
;
run;
```

Program

```
data Y; 
set x; 
array arr(5) a--e; 

array brr(4) b--e; 

do j=1 to dim(arr); 
do i =2 to dim(brr);

    if brr(i)=. then brr(i)=arr(j); 
end;
end;
drop i j;
run;
```

However the output that I get is

```
1 . 1 1 2
2 2 3 2 2
3 3 4 5 6 
4 4 4 2 4
. . 6 6 6
```

Which is wrong! 
The output I want is like this:

```
1 1 1 1 2
2 2 3 3 3
3 3 4 5 6 
4 4 4 2 4
. . 6 6 6
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want `4 4 4 2 2` instead of `4 4 4 2 4` ?

You need only one loop:

Try this code:

```
data Y; 
    set x; 
    array arr(5) a--e; 

    do i=2 to dim(arr); 
        if arr(i)=. then arr(i)=arr(i-1); 
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Also, don't forget to think what is happening in this code!
You could try to check for every row and every i:

- what is the arr(i) value?
- what is the arr(i-1) value?
- is the outcome what is expected? (Convince yourself that the problem is solved :) )